# Spring boot hibernate with H2 DB GeneratedValue annotation clashes with data in data.sql

Tags: sql, spring-boot, api, hibernate, h2

I have been having this issue for quite a while and tried different things, before smashing my head to the wall, I though asking you guys.

I have a simple spring-boot (2.7.5) API that has employees in it:

```
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String surname;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String role;

  public Employee() {
  }

  public Employee(String name, String surname, String role) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setSurname(surname);
    this.setRole(role);
  }

  //... omitting the rest
```

The problem I have been facing is the following: If I don't provide a data.sql where I am trying to initialize the database with some initial values everything works fine. The moment I put that initialization file(available below) I start to get this error:

```
2023-05-31 13:40:13.025  WARN 33823 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2023-05-31 13:40:13.025 ERROR 33823 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'Amy', 'Software Engineer', 'Jakline')"; SQL statement:
```

which I believe is related to the fact that the @GeneratedValue doesn't know about the existing data in the database. In fact, if I try to call the POST to add an employee, the error refers every time to an id that increments, until it gets to an available ID and everything starts working. Follows the data.sql

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, surname, role) VALUES (1, 'Amy', 'Jakline', 'Software Engineer'); 
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, surname, role) VALUES (2, 'Jake', 'Folker', 'Test Analyst') ;
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, surname, role) VALUES (3, 'Charles', 'Hucker', 'Scrum Master') ;
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, surname, role) VALUES (4, 'Terry', 'Roland', 'Developer') ;
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, surname, role) VALUES (5, 'Rosa', 'Marie', 'Technical Solution Architect') ;
COMMIT;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_index ON employee (id);
```

and the application.properties

```
server.port=8080

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:bootapp;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:bootapp;MODE=MySql;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;

spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG


# The following is to avoid conflicts between script based initialisation (schema.sql and data.sql)
# and hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

server.error.path=/error
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false 

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Things that I tried and didn't work:

- using different `strategy = GenerationType.` tried `IDENTITY`, `SEQUENCE`, `AUTO` and `TABLE`
- adding a schema.sql to explicitly create the employee table but that conflicted regardless of the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` setting
- tried changing some of the config settings in application.properties but no joy as well

One thing I tried and worked that **I refuse to use it as a solution as it's so ugly** was to manually handle the generation with a dirty hack like the following (after removing the @GeneratedValue annotation)

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Employee create(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    Long id = 1L;
    // Let's do a ugly loop until we find an available ID
    while (employee.getId() == null || employeeRepository.existsById(employee.getId())) {
        employee.setId(id);
        System.out.println(employee);
        id++;
    }
    return employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

I am sure many of you would have a deep understanding of the issue I am facing because it looks quite a common use-case to have the @GeneratedValue annotation with a database that has some initial values in it (maybe not necessarily with `data.sql` but connecting with an existing db)

If you need any other details about the code I can add it or create a public repo.

Help would be highly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you use identity columns you shouldn't insert own values into them like that:

```sql
INSERT INTO employee (id, name, surname, role) VALUES (1, 'Amy', 'Jakline', 'Software Engineer');
```

Instead of that let database generate them:

```sql
INSERT INTO employee (name, surname, role) VALUES ('Amy', 'Jakline', 'Software Engineer');
```

If this is not an option for some reason, you can adjust generator of identity column after insertion of your values:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX(id) FROM employee) + 1;
```

Comment: ok but would that make any difference if I had already a database with some values in it? Are you implying that because I provide the id explicitly somehow whatever takes care of the generation of ids wouldn't be aware of the already present ids?

Btw I tried that as well but got an error related to the fact I wasn't providing the id value when spring/hibernate was executing the data.sql file, but I haven't tried adding the last line so will give it a go

Comment: Generators of identity columns don't check and shouldn't check values that were inserted into these columns. It means these values may conflict with generated values. But if you already inserted some rows in incorrect way you can still adjust generator with the last command.